# ggbetweenstats: logarithmic y axis removes grouped analysis from plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggstatsplot

I am conducting a kruskal-wallis test to determine statistically significance between three groups of a measurement. I use ggbetweenstats to determine between which group there is a statistically significant association.

Here is the code for sample data and the plot:

```
sampledata <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
                                    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), group = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
                                                                               1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2), measurement = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                          1, 200, 30, 1000, 6000, 1, 0, 0, 10000, 20000, 700, 65, 1, 8, 
                                                                                                                                          11000, 13000, 7000, 500, 3000)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               20L))
```

```
library(ggstatsplot)
library(ggplot2)

ggbetweenstats(
 data = sampledata,
 x = group,
 y = measurement,
 type = "nonparametric",
 plot.type = "box",
 pairwise.comparisons = TRUE,
 pairwise.display = "all",
 centrality.plotting = FALSE,
 bf.message = FALSE
)
```

You can see the results from the kruskal wallis test on the top of the plot as well as the groupes analysis in the plot. Now I want to change y axis to logarithmic scale:

```
ggbetweenstats(
  data = sampledata,
  x = group,
  y = measurement,
  type = "nonparametric",
  plot.type = "box",
  pairwise.comparisons = TRUE,
  pairwise.display = "all",
  centrality.plotting = FALSE,
  bf.message = FALSE
) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(trans=scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 1, base = exp(1)), limits = c(0,25000), breaks = c(0,1,10,100,1000,10000)
)
```

However, this removes the grouped analysis. I have tried different scaling solutions and browsed SO for a solution but couldn't find anything. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `y_position` parameter in the `geom_signif` component is not affected by the y axis transformation. You will need to pass the log values of the desired bracket heights manually. In theory, you can pass these via the `ggsignif.args` parameter, but it seems that in the latest version of `ggstatsplot` this isn't possible because the `y_position` is hard-coded.

One way tound this is to store the plot then change the y positions after the fact. Here's a full reprex with the latest versions of ggplot2, ggstatsplot and their dependencies (at the time of writing)

```r
sampledata <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), group = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2), measurement = c(0, 
1, 200, 30, 1000, 6000, 1, 0, 0, 10000, 20000, 700, 65, 1, 8, 
11000, 13000, 7000, 500, 3000)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
20L))

library(ggstatsplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p <- ggbetweenstats(
  data = sampledata,
  x = group,
  y = measurement,
  type = "nonparametric",
  plot.type = "box",
  pairwise.comparisons = TRUE,
  pairwise.display = "all",
  centrality.plotting = FALSE,
  bf.message = FALSE
) + scale_y_continuous(trans = pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 1, base = exp(1)),
                        limits = c(0, exp(13)), 
                        breaks = c(0, 10^(0:5)),
                        labels = comma)
#> Scale for y is already present.
#> Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale.

i <- which(sapply(p$layers, function(x) inherits(x$geom, "GeomSignif")))
p$layers[[i]]$stat_params$y_position <-  c(10, 10.8, 11.6)

p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Running that code gives me this error:
Error in (function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "signif", position = "identity",  : 
  formal argument "y_position" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: I am not sure but I assume there is some package loaded interfering with y_position argument?

Comment: @Max I updated `ggstatsplot` and now get the same error as you, because `y_position` is hard-coded. There is a work-around though, which I have now put in the answer.